# How to chain JOINs to query a distant table?

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I am writing an app for home use and decided to use SQLite as the database to learn some SQL.

The app works as follows:

- there is a set of `people` who have a name → this information comes from place A and is reflected in the `people` table.
- I have from an unrelated source B some results (table `results`) that contain the result of an `action` and points to a "users reference" (also coming from B)
- I manually linked the two worlds by pointing the source B users to the "people".

[image]

I now would like to get a table of `people.name` who did not do the thing they were suppose to do (i.e. `done` for them is `NULL`).

This is the place where my previous amateur dev experience does not help anymore: how to connect the three tables so that I can `SELECT` from one table (`SELECT name from people`) but put a condition on a table that is two hops away.

I thought that `OUTER JOIN` would be a [solution](https://dataschool.com/how-to-teach-people-sql/sql-join-types-explained-visually/) (and I still think it is) but I have one intermediate table. **Basically I do not know how to "chain" joins**.

How should I approach that?

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join two times:

```sql
SELECT name
 from people
 join app_user on (people.id = app_user.id_people)
 join results on (app_user.id_app = results.id_app and results.done is null)
```

Here we join table `app_user` to table `people`, and then join `results` to previous result.

There is no need for outer join, if table `results` contains row for not done tasks.

If table `results` doesn't contain row for not done tasks, than you'll need outer join with `where` clause.

```sql
SELECT name
 from people
 join app_user on (people.id = app_user.id_people)
 left join results on (app_user.id_app = results.id_app)
where results.done is null
```

Hope this helps with your confusion.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I did not realize that the JOINs are independent.